# conditional compilation inside an enum

Tags: rust

I have something like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
#[macro_use]
extern crate nix;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        DeviceNotFound{
            description("Could not find a ledger device")
        }
        Ioctl ( err: nix::Error ) {
            from()
            description("ioctl error")
            display("ioctl error: {}", err)
            cause(err)
        }
    }
 }
```

The issue I have is that `nix` is only available in linux.

How can I make `Ioctl` conditional to linux? Or that is a bad idea?

I wonder what is the recommended approach in Rust.

An alternative is: can I use the nix crate types even in Windows as long as I dont use any function/method? In that case, I would not need to make this conditional.

---

**Update:**
It seems that the `from()` line is connected to the problem.

@Stargateur definitely works for most cases, but not for my specific question. I am adding a here [Example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7b38b0be26d2a6e0ff0777d7bc24b6f4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        DeviceNotFound{
            description("Could not find a ledger device")
        }
        #[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
        Ioctl ( err: nix::Error ) {
            from()
            description("ioctl error")
            display("ioctl error: {}", err)
            cause(err)
        }
    }
 }

 fn main() {
    let _ = Error::DeviceNotFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using conditional compilation inside quickerror was not possible. After some experimentation I came up with the idea of just mocking the type in platforms where is does not exist:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;
#[macro_use]
extern crate cfg_if;

cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(target_os = "linux")] {
        extern crate nix;
    } else {
        // Mock the type in other target_os
        mod nix {
            quick_error! {
                #[derive(Debug)]
                pub enum Error {}
            }
        }
    }
}

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        DeviceNotFound{
            description("Could not find a ledger device")
        }
        Ioctl ( err: nix::Error ) {
            from()
            description("ioctl error")
            display("ioctl error: {}", err)
            cause(err)
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I completely agree! I dont like it much.. I still dont get why adding from() makes the cfg not to work. I would definitely prefer to do something similar to what you proposed

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make Ioctl conditional to linux?

Normally, you could just put `#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]` in front:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
Ioctl(err: nix::Error) {
    from()
    description("ioctl error")
    display("ioctl error: {}", err)
    cause(err)
}
```

But it's look like `quick_error` doesn't support it, so you could open a request feature on [github](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error/issues) but the crate is not very active (no offence) or you could just don't use this crate and do your Error type "manually".

> I wonder what is the recommended approach in Rust.

It's opinion based, do as you like.

> An alternative is: can I use the nix crate types even in Windows as long as I dont use any function/method? In that case, I would not need to make this conditional.

No, you can't use a crate that doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry about the last sentence. What I meant is: "I can use the types but not any method or nix calls". Anyway, I tested and it is not possible

Comment: With respect to conditional compilation, it does not work inside the struct.. maybe it is because of the quickerror macro?

Comment: I have updated the question and added a playground link. There is some tiny difference that makes things fail. It seems to be connected to the `from()` statement